# NGINX, PHP-FPM - Error log entries missing line breaks

Tags: php, nginx

I've just updated Nginx to version 1.19 which replaces the older version Ubuntu 18's repo has, 1.14.

However, now all my PHP-FPM error log entries are clumped together without line breaks. Does anyone know to resolve this? I don't see anything in Nginx's conf file or PHP-FPM's ini file that might be related.

So instead of:

```
PHP Warning: Undefined variable. 
PHP Warning: File not found.
```

It's now like this which makes the logs very hard to read.

```
Warning: Undefined variable.PHP Warning: File not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77106) about this issue, and from what a PHP developer answered there, unfortunately this behaviour cannot be changed "due to the way how FastCGI works".

They wrote a patch targeting PHP 8.2 though which will separate log entries within a single line by `;` .

Comment: Maybe you should provide a link to that patch in your answer